# How to continuously rotate an image upon clicking a button then stop it upon same button click again

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I'm trying to implement is an image rotator button that continuously rotates an image then stops rotating it as I click on it again.

`<img src="placeholder.png" id = "myImage" alt="placeholderImage">`

`<button onclick="RotateImage()">Rotate</button>`

I'm trying to implement the RotateImage() function on JavaScript **without** the use of JQuery.

Comment: Can you show, what you already tried?

Comment: Have a look at CSS animations and have two - one for rotating and one for not and toggle between the two with your JS function.

Answer (score 1):

Try CSS animations.

```js
function rotateImage() {
  var image = document.getElementById("image");
  if (image.style.webkitAnimationPlayState == "running") {
    image.style.webkitAnimationPlayState = "paused";
  } else {
    image.style.webkitAnimationPlayState = "running";
  }
}
```

```css
#image {
  animation: rotation 1s linear 0s infinite;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes rotation {
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg)
  }
}
```

```html
<img id="image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/76/Hendrik_Voogd_-_Italian_landscape_with_Umbrella_Pines.jpg" height="100">
<button onclick="rotateImage()">toogle rotation</button>
```

Variable `element.style.webkitAnimationPlayState` can be `running` (animation is running) or `paused` (animation is paused).

**Picture credits:**
Hendrik Voogd, Public domain, Wikimedia Commons